# Adding style to string table is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a string HTML as follows in a jquery call

```
var template = '<html >' +

'<head>' +
'<h1>Most important heading here</h1>'+

'</head>' +
'<body>' +

'<table border="2px" class="ExlTable"><tr bgcolor="#87AFC6">{table}</table>' +

'</body></html>';
```

I am loading an existing table data into this `{table}`

I want to set the size of this table th and td, I am using

```
$('th').css('width', '200');
$('th').css('height', '30');
$('td').css('height', '30');
```

This is working, but it affects all the table on the page, so I tried like below 2 types, but not working

```
$('.ExlTable th').css('width', '200');
$('.ExlTable th').css('height', '30');
$('.ExlTable td').css('height', '30');
```

Not working

```
var $template = $(template);
$template.find('th').css('width', '200');
$template.find('th').css('height', '30');
$template.find('td').css('height', '30');
```

Not working, please help

Comment: please provide minimal working code.

Comment: what is the content in {table}

Comment: This doesn't look right, your template variable should be `${template}` and wrapped in ` and you don't need the +. You also have a h1 in <head> which is not correct either. Read more on template literals here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: JM is your problem solved? You haven't provided us with any feedback

Answer (score 2):

You `template` does not contains any `thead` or `th` for that matter, so that is why your code is "not" working.

I've added `thead` and `th` to your code and then everything is working just fine.

```js
var template = '<html >' +

'<head>' +
'<h1>Most important heading here</h1>'+

'</head>' +
'<body>' +

'<table border="2px" class="ExlTable"><thead><tr><th>TableHeader</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr bgcolor="#87AFC6"><td>{table}</td></tbody></table>' +

'</body></html>';

var $template = $(template);
$template.find('th').css('width', '200');
$template.find('th').css('height', '30');
$template.find('td').css('height', '30');

$(".tableContainer").html($template)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tableContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use old fashion css:

```
<style>
.ExlTable th {
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
}
.ExlTable td {
    height:30px;
}
</style>
```

make sure you have properly formatted your table content in the `{table}` variable

Comment: I agree that normally it's better to use "old fashion css" but in this case it's not the css that is the problem but the html.

Comment: If he's variable `{table}` contains a table, then he has a table within a table, and the first table would be incorrect HTML, as you can see in this line `<table border="2px" class="ExlTable"><tr bgcolor="#87AFC6">{table}</table>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give width/height into specific measurement like percentage or px

For ex :

```
var $template = $(template);
$template.find('th').css('width', '200px');
$template.find('th').css('height', '30px');
$template.find('td').css('height', '30px');
```

or

```
var $template = $(template);
$template.find('th').css('width', '50%');
$template.find('th').css('height', '30%');
$template.find('td').css('height', '20%');
```

Comment: If there is no value behind the number it will use `px` as default.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing td, but this might help you.

```
$("#test").html(template);
$("#test").find('th').css('width', '200');
$("#test").find('th').css('height', '30');
$("#test").find('td').css('height', '30');
```

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ehswvb50/)